# Rails custom model method in where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

In my rails app I have defined in the `Kid` model a calculation based on the fields from the `Kids` DB. the method is as follows:

```
def flip_date 
  self.dob.advance(months: 10) 
end
```

I want to use this in my controller as I have a method where I am defining something as follows:

```
new_kids = Kid.where(discharge_date: nil).where('flip_date > ?', Date.current.advance(year: 1).beginning_of_year)
```

However I keep getting the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: flip_date: SELECT "kids".* FROM "kids" WHERE "kids"."discharge_date" IS NULL AND (flip_date < '2017-01-01')
```

Any ideas on how can I make this work? All help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you will have to use `scope` see the syntax and examples in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope)

Comment: @ImranAli I looked through the documentation but I still do not think it will solve the problem, as there is still a query happening the `scope` definitions but `flip_date` is not a column

Comment: @AlvinLau what are you trying to achieve through where query? where method will create SQL statement, you will not be able to use model methods in sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use model methods take a look at http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select

For your case:

```
new_kids = Kid.where(discharge_date: nil).select{|k| k.flip_date > Date.current.advance(year: 1).beginning_of_year}
```

But select method takes every object in memory before returning final result. Hence I will advise to use normal where clause and instead of flip_date take dob (which is a column in database) in consideration.

Like this

```
new_kids = Kid.where(discharge_date: nil).where('dob > ?', <date criteria>)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, the select command. Thank you!

Comment: select returns Array.
How can I get the ActiveRecord_Relation instead of Array?

Comment: @hobbydev I am looking for the same. Did you find anything on "How can I get the ActiveRecord_Relation instead of Array?" ?

Answer (score 0):

The select method (http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select) works great if you are okay with the return being an Array.

I am still looking for a way to do this with an ActiveRecord_Relation return.

If others know how to do this, it would be much appreciated if you can share.

Answer (score 0):

This example doesn't respond to your specific code, but to the extent it helps someone else with a similar question, here's a very simple example of how `.select` can be really handy:

```
@expired_memberships = User.select{|u| u.membership_expired_yesterday?}
```

In that example you've looped through all your Users and filtered them based on a custom method you defined on the `User` model (`membership_expired_yesterday?`). Now you can easily do stuff with that collection like this example in a mailer:

```
@expirations.each do |user|
  MembershipExpirationMailer.with(user: user).first_reminder.deliver_now
end
```